# Is it possible to use recursive cell formulas in org-mode tables?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to build a column that begins with a constant, say, 1, and whose succeeding rows are double the preceding row (or some variable coefficient I set in the formula):

```
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 4  |
| 8  |
| 16 |
```

Is there a way to quickly set this up in Emacs? I see that there are row formulas, column formulas, and rectangular region formulas, but I don't see any recursion or quick formula replication in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#+TBLFM: @1$1=1::@<<..>$1=@-1 * 2
```

will produce that table recursively. Put the cursor on the last row and hit <kbd>C-u C-u C-c *</kbd> `@<<..>` is a range from second to the last row.

```
#+TBLFM: @1$1=0::@2$1=1::@<<<..>$1=@-1 + @-2
```

will produce the Fibonacci Sequence

Comment: So if I want to apply that formula in column 3, I add the formula `@1$3=1::@<<..>$3=@-1 * 2`? The result still ends up in column 1 for some reason.

Comment: I played around a little bit with field formulas. Something like #+TBLFM: @2$3..>$3=@-1 * 2::@1$3=2::@2$1..>$1=@-1 * 3 will set the third column but will fail to set the first column since ranges are rectangular regions according to the documentation. The best that I could come up with was #+TBLFM: @2$3..>$3='(cond ((= $# 1) (* 2 @-1)) ((= $# 2) (* 3 @-1)) (t (* 4 @-1)));L::@1$1=4::@1$2=3::@1$3=2 The range seems like it should be @2$1..>$3, but that will just restrict it to the first column.

Comment: That is #+TBLFM: @2$3..>$3=@-1 * 2::@1$3=2 will set the third column. Adding the first column setting will cause an error.

Comment: Please [edit] the answer and add the [inline](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) keyboard (`kbd`) and [code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) (`\``) formatting